# Why LinkedHashMap is ordered?

Tags: java, collections

Why is `LinkedHashMap` is ordered?
If it implements the `Map` interface and extends `AbstractMap` and `HashMap`, 
Which of them provides the ordering feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).

So the ordering comes from the implementation of LinkedHashMap and not from extending `java.util.AbstractMap<K,V>` or `java.util.HashMap<K,V>`

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedHashMap` is ordered because that is part of its contract. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html, for example "Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order.".

It also states how it is different from `HashMap`: "This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries."